# dplyr: case_when warning: the argument 'pattern' has longitud > 1

Tags: r, dplyr

I've a vector of longitud > 1, and when running the following code I get:

```
Warning message:
In grepl(uei_secciones_sheet$ga_page, pagePath, ignore.case = TRUE) :
  the argument 'pattern' has longitud > 1, only the first element will be applied.
```

I need to: put "Salud" in a new column `secciones` when the elements in `df$pagePath` contains any of the elements of `where_to_look_up$values_to_match`.

My code:

```
df<- df %>%
  mutate(
    secciones = case_when(
      grepl(where_to_look_up$values_to_match, pagePath, ignore.case = TRUE) ~ "Salud"
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could `paste` the 'values_to_match' as a single string with `collapse` as `|` as `pattern` in `grep` is not vectorized.  Either we loop over the `patterns` and then do a `reduce` or simple `collapse` the vectors into a single string with `|`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   mutate(
     secciones = case_when(
          grepl(paste(where_to_look_up$values_to_match, collapse="|"), 
         pagePath, ignore.case = TRUE) ~ "Salud"
     )
  )
```